# `0x15` returns 00010101, not

Tags: c, binary, literals

Hi I'm mangling with the bit-wise representation in c programming

I printed out `0x15` expecting `0000 1111` but got `0001 0101`. Which is `0x21`.

I used this macro to print out the number in binary

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define BYTE_TO_BINARY_PATTERN_1BYTE "%c%c%c%c %c%c%c%c"
#define BYTE_TO_BINARY(byte)    \
    (byte & 0x80 ? '1' : '0'), \
    (byte & 0x40 ? '1' : '0'), \
    (byte & 0x20 ? '1' : '0'), \
    (byte & 0x10 ? '1' : '0'), \
    (byte & 0x08 ? '1' : '0'), \
    (byte & 0x04 ? '1' : '0'), \
    (byte & 0x02 ? '1' : '0'), \
    (byte & 0x01 ? '1' : '0')

int main(){
    printf(BYTE_TO_BINARY_PATTERN_1BYTE, BYTE_TO_BINARY(0x15));
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm suspecting that maybe there is a specific way a hexadecimal literals are saved in the memory, could anyone see what I'm missing here?

Or, the Hexadecimals are saved as 4bytes in the memory and there is some sort of error in the macro script that I'm using?

Comment: There's an important difference between `0x15` and `15`.

Comment: `0x09 + 1` is `0x0a`, not `0x10`!

Comment: Except as text in a string (and the rare use of BCD), all integers are stored in the same way. There is no "hexadecimal storage" or "decimal storage". Decimal, octal, hexadecimal, are different human readable ways of expressing the same value.

Comment: Each hexadecimal digit is mapped to 4 binary digits. 1 (hexadecimal) is mapped to 0001 (binary). 5 (hexadecimal) is mapped to 0101 (binary). 2 (hexadecimal) is mapped to 0010 (binary).

Comment: The constant `0x15` is the same as the constant `21`.  The constant `0xf` is the same as the constant `15`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

15 would give you 00001111.

But 0x15 will give you 00010101, which is 21 (not 0x21).

Comment: While you are at it, 015 will give you 13 - the leading 0 converts it to octal.

Comment: God something must have been gotten into my head thinking hexa 15 is 1111, this was a stupid question. Thanks!!

Comment: Perhaps you should write those numbers as 0b00001111 and 0b0010101 (even though the 0b prefix is currently nonstandard in C) because 0x00001111 and 0x00010101 are wrong.